# Can I install laminate flooring over linoleum which is torn?

Tags: laminate-floor, remodeling, linoleum

I have a small hallway/entryway with cheap linoleum. (Approximately 8 ft by 3 ft.) Part of it is torn, exposing the concrete floor underneath.

I have enough laminate (simulated wood) flooring left over from finishing another room and would like to replace the linoleum. A friend says I can go right over the top of the linoleum and that the difference in height from the concrete to the linoleum wouldn't matter. Further, the linoleum is supposed to be very difficult to remove. (I haven't tried yet.)

Because it's torn, exposing concrete, I am thinking it shouldn't be that hard to remove. Am I wasting my time trying to remove it, or should I follow my friend's advice and install the laminate flooring over the top of it?

(This question is related: [Should I remove old linoleum when replacing a linoleum floor?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/1596/should-i-remove-old-linoleum-when-replacing-a-linoleum-floor))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either way will work. My first impression would be to try to remove the old lino, especially since there is so little of it.  If it turns out it too difficult, then simply remove all the loose lino, lay down your foam underlayment and go right over the whole mess.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what my parents (or rather their contractors) did to their kitchen when a chair leg started scratching up the lino badly enough to show the concrete underneath. The contractors simply cut away as much as they could of the torn part so it was as flat as possible, then added a later of Tyvek (cause the lino WAS right on the slab) and then the laminate (Pergo, I think they had). Job looks great after 10 years.